# How can I make this code work in Sql Server CE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

This code was written by someone else, and I am having difficulty implementing it as I only have access to SQl Server CE:

```
SELECT *
FROM Space AS S1
WHERE (Centre_Name = 'Sandton') AND (Revision_No =
 (SELECT        MAX(Revision_No)
 FROM            Spaces AS S2
 WHERE        (S2.Centre_Name = S1.Centre_Name) AND (S2.Space_No = S1.Space_No)
 GROUP BY S1.Centre_Name, S1.Space_No))
```

Comment: the code seems ine, what errors do you get?

Comment: Maybe `FROM Space AS S1` --> `FROM [Space] AS S1`

Comment: The error I get in Visual Studio is There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 79, Token in error = SELECT]

Comment: Is it possible that Sql Server CE (whatever it is) does not support *correlated queries*?

Comment: I'm not sure, I know it has issues with them. There must be a workaround.